# Write to channel blocked forever

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I am stuck in a strange situation where the write operation to the channel never happens.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    s := make(chan bool)
    k := make(chan bool)
    fmt.Println("start")
    go func() {
    fmt.Println("routine 1")
        s <- true
    }()
    go func() {
    fmt.Println("routine 2")
        for {
            select {
            case  <-s :
                for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
                    fmt.Println("before")
                    c <- i
                    fmt.Println("after")
                }       
            case <- k :
                fmt.Println("k ready")
                break
            }
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("routine 3")
        for {
            select {
                case x := <- c :
                fmt.Println("x=", x)
                k <- true
                fmt.Println("k done")

            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

And here is the output:

```
start
routine 1
routine 2
before
routine 3
x= 0
after
before
```

I wonder why the write to the channel k blocks, but the log statement `fmt.Println("k ready")` is never printed.

Here is what I think :

- go routine 1 writes true to channel s
- go routine 2 writes 0 to
  channel c and waits because buffer size is 0, it will not be able to
  write '1' to it unless someone reads channel c
- go routine 3 comes into the picture, reads channel c (now go routine 2
  can write to c once go routine 2 resumes) prints the value of x. **NOW IT SHOULD BE ABLE TO WRITE TO CHANNEL K but that is not happening**

According to me it should be able to write to channel k then case 2 of goroutine should execute and print "k ready"

Can anyone explain me why write to the channel blocked?
As a fix I know I can increase the buffer size of channel c and everything will get printed but I am not interested in fixing this, instead I want to understand this scenario.

A nice [blog](https://www.goinggo.net/page/3.html) to understand the above case.

Comment: Link to above code is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/3YL2eoTVn1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a deadlock.

- goroutine 1 writes to `s` then quits
- goroutine 2 reads from `s`, and writes to `c`
- goroutine 3 reads from `c`, and writes to `k`, and this blocks because nothing is reading from `k`, because goroutine 2 is blocked in the write to `k` above.
- goroutine 2 writes to `c` again which blocks as goroutine 3 is still trying to write to `k` and thus is not reading from `c`

Contrary to what you say, you don't have a buffer size of 1. You have a buffer size of zero (i.e. an unbuffered channel), so a write will block until something reads. This is probably the source of your misunderstanding. Per the [language specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types):

> A new, initialized channel value can be made using the built-in function `make`, which takes the channel type and an optional capacity as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(chan int, 100)
> ```
>
> The capacity, in number of elements, sets the size of the buffer in the channel. If the capacity is zero or absent, the channel is unbuffered and communication succeeds only when both a sender and receiver are ready. Otherwise, the channel is buffered and communication succeeds without blocking if the buffer is not full (sends) or not empty (receives). A nil channel is never ready for communication.

Comment: Thanks @abligh for the reply but it seems like there is some typo or i misunderstood your answer.
Point#2 : write to channel k happens in go routine 3
Also goroutine 3 will never execute as per you?

Comment: And understand the buffer size concept you mention but i wrongly said size 1 instead of 0, I read that [here](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines).
Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @sheikhsabeer I've fixed deadlock explanation

Comment: @sheikhsabeer nothing in that link I can see suggests `make` on a channel without an argument makes a buffered channel with buffer size 1. `make` without an argument makes an unbuffered channel. The difference is explained at the bottom of https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/10 and more formally at https://golang.org/ref/spec#Channel_types - I will edit the answer to include this.

Comment: thanks again for the reply
Couple of question to the updated explanation :
Point#3 : if goroutine 3 writes to the channel then output should have log `k done` and goroutine 2 is only reading channel `k` not writing to it.

Comment: @sheikhsabeer no need to thank - just upvote and (if this ends up the best answer) accept the answer with the 'tick'.

Comment: I am not saying that making channel without args make channel of size 1.
In case of unbuffered channel this should work
chan <- val
<-chan
but not 
<-chan
chan <-val